# Laravel one validation function for Store and Update

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-validation

I am trying to have one validation function for both store and update. So I don't repeat code. It works well. The problem is testing 'unique'. I worked around with this idea. But feels long-winded. Is there a better way to do it?

- I want to check for unique at the store.
- At update, unique check ignores own id.
- I don't want different validations like I did as the user will be
  first notified of the unique error, he will fix it. then something
  else might be wrong and he has to fix again.

.

```
public function validateRequest($request){
    
    if($request->method() == "PUT")
    {
        $val = $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'unique:customers,id',
            'phone' => 'unique:customers,id',
        ]);
    }

    if($request->method() == "POST"){
        $val = $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'unique:customers',
            'phone' => 'unique:customers'
        ]);
    }

    $validation = $this->validate($request, [
       'name' => 'required',
       'phone' => 'required|integer|gt:0',
       'phone2' => 'nullable|integer|gt:0|',
       'email' => 'email|nullable',
       'note' => 'nullable',
    ],
    [
        'phone.integer' => "Invalid phone format. Use international format. Eg: 971550000000",
        'phone2.integer' => "Invalid phone format. Use international format. Eg: 971550000000",
        'required' => "Required Field",
    ]);
    
    return $validation;
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing this, you can also make an array of rules in the same function and write a few `if conditions` for input fields that which fields should be validated and which are not.

Comment: here is a good read for you, https://asklagbox.com/blog/form-request-store-update , an answer on here for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/37771939/2109233